# jquery .html is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to attach a variable into my HTML. I am using .html to do this but doesn't seem to be working.

Also am I right to use the pageinit event? The page is dynamic , the content is different depending on the choice from a list on the previous page.

Maybe append would be a better choice? Im unsure.. Any advice?

Here is my JS file

```
 $(document).on('pageinit','#details-page', function(){
      var details_view = "";
      $(function() {
        $.getJSON('js/bands.json', function(data) {
            details_view += '<div><p>Content goes here</p></div>';
         });
  });
  $('#detail_content').html(details_view);
});
```

Here is my HTML.

```
<div data-role="page" id="details-page">
    <div data-role="header" class="header">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="detail_content">
        // **I want the details_view variable content to go here**
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" class="footer" data-position="fixed">           
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

Comment: That wouldn't be of use to me- Im new to this, and when posting it, I did not understand 'asynchronous callback function'.. there will be others in the same situation. Thanks for the cue

Comment: Well you're right that there'll be others :) This is a huge, huge stumbling block. (So don't feel bad about it!! It confuses almost everybody.)

Comment: If I remeber correctly you can set async: false. Then it will not be asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is an AJAX method. `A` stands for asynchronous, which means it will be finished later in the future. Whatever you want to happen when the request is finished, you should do it in the callback:

```
$.getJSON('js/bands.json', function(data) {
    details_view += '<div><p>Content goes here</p></div>';
    $('#detail_content').html(details_view);
});
```

Comment: Cheers, I just tried it, adn it still didnt work - useful to know though, thanks!

Comment: When I use this   -- " $("[data-role=content]").append(details_view); ", it works but it also adds the variable to the index page 'data-role=content'. Does this give any clue?

Comment: @user3266422 Do you have an element in the page with the ID of `detail_content`? :)

Comment: the div in the HTML has an id of called detail_content

Comment: @user3266422 In the HTML you pasted, you have `details-page`, not `details_page`.

Comment: The .html code is referring to detail_content... which is the div inside details-page (my naming is terrible.. note to self)

Comment: On init of #details-page, find variable 'details_view' and add it to the #detail_content div - in a nutshell

Comment: @user3266422 I see now, got confused. In that case, it should work. As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94FBu/), the code itself works, so there must be something on your side that causes the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know. You've been very helpful, I'll keep trying :)

Comment: The difference is the getJSON so maybe it's that

Answer (score 2):

Your `$.getJSON()` call is **asynchronous**. The line of code that calls `.html()` will run long before the data is returned.

Comment: Thanks that is good to know! I moved the .html code inside the getJSON function, as suggested by @kapa